# System.IO.StreamWriter : Why do I have to use keyword "using"

Tags: c#, text, using, streamwriter

```
//C#
using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = 
    new System.IO.StreamWriter("me00.txt", true))
{
    writer.WriteLine("Hey"); //saved 
}
System.IO.StreamWriter writer02 = new System.IO.StreamWriter("me01.txt", true);
writer02.WriteLine("Now hey x2"); //not saved
```

File me00.txt and me01.txt are created, however only the first file's content gets saved.

me00.txt will have line hey. me01.txt will be an empty txt file; "Now hey x2" is not saved.

What does the keyword "using" do to cause this observation?

Comment: Never ever open a steam of something and don't close it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to use "using".   It's just a shortcut to keep you from doing even *more* typing...

The alternative is to nest the whole thing in a try-finally construct like the following:

```
 System.IO.StreamWriter writer = null; 

 try
 {
     writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("me00.txt", true);
     writer.WriteLine("Hey");
 }
 finally
 {
     if (writer != null)
        writer.Dispose();
 )
```

When the writer is disposed, it is also *closed*, which is the step you're missing.   The *using* presents a tidy way to do all of this compactly.

Answer (score 1):

Flush the [Buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It works with the using statement, because the buffer is flushed when the stream being disposed/closed.

Just call `writer02.Flush();`

From the MSDN on [StreamWriter.Flush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

> Flushing the stream will not flush its underlying encoder unless you explicitly call Flush or Close

Also, you need to dispose the Stream. Don't forget to call the [Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227564%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method when you are done with the stream.
The using statement will do it for you. If you call Dispose, you might not need to call Flush.

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
writer02.Close();
```

--------------:

```
public void Test()
    {
        //C#
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("me00.txt", true))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Hey"); 
        }
    }
```

Because this code is identical to the code

```
        public void Test()
    {
        //C#
        System.IO.StreamWriter writer = null;
        try
        {
            writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("me01111.txt", true);
            writer.WriteLine("Hey"); //saved 
        }
        finally
        {
            if (writer != null) //Flush data
            {
                ((IDisposable)writer).Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```